# Cannot build the Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreen sample due to missing references

Tags: c#, .net, build, nuget, caliburn.micro

I've downloaded the source package of Caliburn.Micro from [this page](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/releases/view/108277), version 1.5.2. I have VS2010 Professional, and I have downloaded and installed the Blend SDK.

I've extracted the entire thing, and was able to build the actual Caliburn.Micro.DLL after removing the projects that aren't supported on my system (meaning I can build Caliburn.Micro.DLL only).

However, I cannot figure out how to properly build the HelloScreens sample. It appears that the sample is configured to use NuGet, but whatever I do I can't seem to get the proper references to work.

I've tried right-clicking the solution end enabling NuGet package restore, hoping that the thing would be smart enough to resolve what it had to resolve, but nope.

The following references have yellow exclamation points on them (and don't exist on disk):

1. Caliburn.Micro
2. Microsoft.Expression.Effects
3. Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
4. System.Windows.Interactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .csproj file for the sample points to `..\..\..\bin\Silverlight\Debug\Caliburn.Micro.dll`, which doesn't exist on my file system since I didn't build the Silverlight version. Building that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can you remove the Caliburn Nuget package through Visual Studio and reinstall it? Your packages.config might be mixed up. Nuget should then set the references right.

Comment: Well, after reading your response, I opened the .csproj file and looked for the reference (I don't normally delve into there) and see that it's pointing to the Silverlight version of the DLL, which doesn't exist on disk. That would explain it...